# Getting Y position from Latitude on a spherical projected map

Tags: javascript, maps, latitude-longitude

In Javascript.

I have a map of the world that is 1024 x 1024px  - It is a spherical Mercator projection.

Im looking to convert long/lat to x,y for this map. I have a bunch of coordinates that I need to overlay on top of it.

Calculating longitude was very easy, and I am doing it like so:

```
pos.x = ((long + 180)/ 360) * 1024;
```

I just need to same for lat --> y

I looked around a saw a lot of reference to openlayers, but didn't see such a conversion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To boil it down:

```
var mercator = function(lat, lng) {
  return [lng, Math.log( (Math.sin(lat) + 1.0) / Math.cos(lat)) ] ;
};
```

Lat and long must be expressed in *radians* of course.

Comment: Thanks! If anyone needs it, here you go `pos.y = ((Math.log( (Math.sin(lat) + 1.0) / Math.cos(lat))) + (Math.PI) ) / (2 * Math.PI) * 1024`

Comment: Above needs radians not degrees

Answer (score -1):

You can find the corresponding formulas in this wikipedia article: [Mercator Projection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercator_projection).

Comment: So I tried this... but that does not seem to work. I get undefined values above/below 60º `pos.y = Math.log(Math.tan((Math.PI/ 4) + (lat/2)));`

Comment: `tan()` expects the argument in radians. Please multiply your angle by `PI/180` to convert it accordingly.

Comment: Feel a little stupid not doing that before, but it is still not working. -90 is giving an infinite measurement. And 90 is giving 37.33 `pos.y = Math.log(Math.tan((Math.PI/ 4) + ( (lat * (Math.PI/180) ) /2)));`

Comment: @Adam Yes, this is one of the unfortunate properties of mercator.